# syncthing + apache reverse proxy for multiple users

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, reverse-proxy, syncthing

OK so I'm having a bit of a mare.

On a computer I have three users, say `user1`, `user2`, and `user3`. Each user is running syncthing and listening on `8384`/`22000`, `8385`/`22001` and `8386`/`22002` respectively.

For each user I have set up an Apache Virtual host with a reverse proxy. The contents of the virtual host file is (say for `user1`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName user1.syncthing.mydomain.com

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / "http://localhost:8384/"
ProxyPassReverse / "http://localhost:8384/"
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from localhost
</Proxy>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/user1_syncthing_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/user1_syncthing_access.log combined

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =user1.syncthing.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have verified syncthing is running for each user on the correct ports

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep syncthing | grep LISTEN
syncthing   649         user2   12u  IPv6  23903      0t0  TCP *:22001 (LISTEN)
syncthing   649         user2   17u  IPv4  19216      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8385 (LISTEN)
syncthing   656         user1   16u  IPv6  14254      0t0  TCP *:22000 (LISTEN)
syncthing   656         user1   19u  IPv4  23931      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8384 (LISTEN)
syncthing   668         user3   13u  IPv6  23921      0t0  TCP *:22002 (LISTEN)
syncthing   668         user3   19u  IPv4  18427      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8386 (LISTEN)
```

In adddition trying to connect to `user1.syncthing.mydomain.com`, `user2.syncthing.mydomain.com` and `user3.syncthing.mydomain.com` from a remote computer all sends me to the correct IP address.

But! The setup is *only* working for `user1`! Using telnet to check the connection on the server for `user2` and `user3` tells me

```
Trying <correct IP address>
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

and from a remote computer tells me (after a pause)

```
Trying <correct IP address>
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

I also tried changing the virtual host file for `user3` to match `user1` but the problem remained.

This set up worked when I first set it up about a week ago and the syncing of folders with the machines that was set up on at the time still works, I'm just having trouble getting to the configuration GUI.

I'm guessing there's something about the actual serving of the page I'm getting wrong but I'm losing hair trying to work out what.

Comment: Wait, how do your examples even distinguish "user1" and "user2" and "user3" if you're telnetting to the same IP address in all of them?

Comment: `telnet user1.syncthing.mydomain.com 80`, `telnet user2.syncthing.mydomain.com 80`, and `telnet user3.syncthing.mydomain.com 80`. First one connects, other two don't.

Comment: Aha, some progress though! Your question prompted me to connect from outside the network instead of internally and it seemed to work OK. I'm gonna go look at router  settings, maybe I'm doing something wrong when I'm hairpinning...

Comment: Ugh...  haven't confirmed yet but in the host entries in Hostnames I had a typo. user2.syncthing.mydomain.com and user3.syncthing.mydomain.com pointed to 192.168.10.12 instead of 192.168.20.12 which user1.syncthing.mydomain.com pointed to. >.< haven't verified yet but seems a likely culprit! thanks for you help!

Comment: yep, we're back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was in how I was hairpinning - I fat fingered the IP address when adding in the Host Entry: `user1.syncthing.mydomain.com` pointed at 192.168.20.12 (correct) but `user2.syncthing.mydomain.com` and `user3.syncthing.mydomain.com` both pointed at 192.168.10.12 (incorrect).

When I said that telnet was going to the right address in the problem description I hadn't noticed the `10`/`20` difference!